# Read the display attribute from MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in mvc how can we read the [display] attribute from the model in a controller

```
  public class RFModelIntro
{
    [Display(Name = "Your Email*")]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

if this is a model , how can i read display property

i tried this code , but no success

```
     //convert to key val pair first
      var model_keys = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(RFModelIntro))
                          .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                          .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.DisplayName);
        string model_val = "";  
   model_keys.TryGetValue("Email", out model_val);
```

model_val is still returning "Email"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<RFModelIntro, string>(x => x.Name, ViewData).DisplayName;
```

Comment: @Nikesh ViewData What this is ? This will cause a build error

Answer (score -1):

You can read this by accessing the DisplayAttribute

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=netcore-3.1=

```
Object[] attr = yourInstance
  .GetType()
  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);

...

var display = attr[0].Name;
```